# What should I do to parse an URL?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing

```
System.out.println("xmlns = " + attributes.getValue("xmlns"));
```

I know my approach is wrong, yet what should I use instead of `attributes.getValue(...)`

`xmls` is a link for example: `https://fkfdkfkf.com`

Comment: i want to get the string not a numerical value

Comment: I think we might need a bit more context here.  What is the type of attributes?  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
   Attributes attributes)

Comment: i dont need the real link but only the string

Answer (score 0):

```
        URL url = new URL("https://fkfdkfkf.com");
        System.out.println(url.getProtocol());
        System.out.println(url.getHost());
        System.out.println(url.getPath());
```